# how to remove dotted outline of square on focus of button using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button which greater than sign or `<` or inverted triangle .I am facing one issue when I focus to that button it show me square .
[image]

**Expected behaviour** : it should show dotted line side of `<` sign or inverted triangle. not whole square dotted line .

If that is not possible can we remove this dotted line without removing current css .we can update the css .but we can't not delete original css
here is my code

https://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/MWmZxPj

```css
.cls-nav__btn {
    background: none;
    border: solid currentColor;
    border-width: 0 4px 4px 0;
    color: #3A3631;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 22px;
    margin-top: -16px;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transition: border-color .3s;
    width: 22px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.cls-nav__btn_prev {
    left:500px;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(135deg);
}

button:focus, a:focus {
    outline-offset: 2px;
    outline-width: 2px !important;
    outline-style: dotted !important;
    outline-color: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="cls-nav">
    <button class="cls-nav__btn cls-nav__btn_prev" tabindex="-1" type="button" value="<"></button>
</div>
<div class="cls__track" id="slider1-track" style="">
</div>
```

Comment: If i understood that second part correctly, just remove the ```outline-style: dotted !important;``` in your focus if you don't want it to select like that.

Comment: Could you put the dots on not with an outline but with a pseudo element absolutely placed 2px away.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any technique to show half the outline, but you can sure remove it.

Just add the following css:

```css
.cls-nav button:focus, 
.cls-nav a:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

**Edit: thought about it - found a way**

@Brandon's answer got me on the track of completely hiding it as I did, and then adding a pseudo-element that will emulate the half-outline.

```css
.cc .cls .cls-nav__btn {
            background: none;
            border: solid currentColor;
            background: none;
            border-width: 0 4px 4px 0;
            color: #3A3631;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 0;
            height: 22px;
            margin-top: -16px;
            padding: 2px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            transition: border-color .3s;
            width: 22px;
            z-index: 5;
        }

        .cc .cls .cls-nav__btn_prev {
          left:500px;
            transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(135deg);
        }

 
         button:focus, a:focus {
            outline-offset: 2px;
            outline-width: 2px !important;
            outline-style: dotted !important;
            outline-color: currentColor;
        }

.cls-nav button:focus, 
.cls-nav a:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}

.cls-nav button:focus::after, 
.cls-nav a:focus::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -7px;
  bottom: -7px;
  left: -3px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: dotted red;
  background: none;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="cc">
    <div id="slider1" class="cls cls--fade cls--ltr cls--draggable slick-active"
         style="visibility: visible;">
        <div class="cls-nav">
            <button class="cls-nav__btn cls-nav__btn_prev" tabindex="-1" type="button"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="cls__track" id="slider1-track" style="">
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

```css
.cls-nav button:focus::after, 
.cls-nav a:focus::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -7px;
  bottom: -7px;
  left: -3px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: dotted red;
  background: none;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

Comment: this will also remove focus when user tab using tab key.. it will create a11y issue

Comment: I don't see an issue here. You asked how to remove the outline. Now you're free to show focus in a different manner for users navigating with keyboard: change color, set a shadow, magnify the arrow, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo elements can help you here. Just as an example, remove your focus and add this and you'll see what i mean. From there you can play around with it.

```
  button:focus::before {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-top: 3px dotted black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use box shadow to achieve the inverted triangle. I am not sure if you want a dotted line or full line. But, this will definitely help to create an illusion of only half a border/outline.

```
button:focus, a:focus {
       box-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0px 2px white, 0px 0px 0px 2px black;
    }
```

Output:
[image: After making changes]

This works because of the 2 shadows. One white and the other black. You can play around with it until you get exactly what you need.